# How to find a child from the styled listbox in WPF?

Tags: wpf, listbox, styles, children

Listbox has the style in which itemtemplate consists of expander and inside expander there is a one more listbox, listbox inside the expander has to be accessed. So how to go ahead?

Answer (score 0):

What data does the inner list box contain? Does your outer object contain a list of child objects as a property? If so, bind the inner listbox's `ItemsSource` to that property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the listbox from code, this is probably what you're looking for: [How to: Find DataTemplate-Generated Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx). It shows how to traverse the visual tree to find the generated elements. Using the visual tree is not a good solution usually though, so consider using data binding instead if at all possible.